# How to tweak table generation in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Could you help me tweak the shiny code below? The first code is just to show the averages I got from my `Test` database. You can see that I only have an average for Fridays, with that in Shiny I would like to present these averages if I choose to see until a day that is Friday in the `daterange`, but it is not working very well. It works only if I put it in the `daterange` from 01/11 to 05/11, but if I choose 02/11 to 05/11, for example, it doesn't work. Also, if I input 01/11 through 02/11 it shows the averages, however, it would not have to be shown as none of those dates are Friday. I inserted three images for you to see. How can I adjust this in code?

**First code**

```
library(dplyr)

   Test <- structure(list(date1 = as.Date(c("2021-11-01","2021-11-01","2021-11-01","2021-11-01")),
                           date2 = as.Date(c("2021-10-22","2021-10-22","2021-10-29","2021-10-29")), 
                           Week = c("Friday", "Friday", "Friday", "Friday"),
                           Category = c("FDE", "ABC", "FDE", "ABC"), 
                           time = c(4, 6, 6, 3)), class = "data.frame",row.names = c(NA, -4L))
  meanTest<-Test%>%
      group_by(Week,Category)%>%
      summarize(mean(time))
    > meanTest

  Week   Category    `mean(time)`
1 Friday ABC               4.5
2 Friday FDE               5
```

**Second code**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(dplyr)

Test <- structure(list(date1 = as.Date(c("2021-11-01","2021-11-01","2021-11-01","2021-11-01")),
                       date2 = as.Date(c("2021-10-22","2021-10-22","2021-10-29","2021-10-29")), 
                       Week = c("Friday", "Friday", "Friday", "Friday"),
                       Category = c("FDE", "ABC", "FDE", "ABC"), 
                       time = c(4, 6, 6, 3)), class = "data.frame",row.names = c(NA, -4L))
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
                    br(),
                    tabPanel("",
                             sidebarLayout(
                               sidebarPanel(
                                 uiOutput('daterange')
                               ),
                               mainPanel(
                                 dataTableOutput('table')
                                 
                               )
                             ))
  ))

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  data <- reactive(Test)
  
  output$daterange <- renderUI({
    dateRangeInput("daterange1", "Period you want to see:",
                   min   = min(data()$date1))
  })
  
  
  
  data_subset <- reactive({
    req(input$daterange1)
    req(input$daterange1[1] <= input$daterange1[2])
    days <- seq(input$daterange1[1], input$daterange1[2], by = 'day')
    Test <- filter(data(),
                   date1 %in% days | 
                     date2 %in% days)
    
    meanTest<-Test%>%
      group_by(Week,Category)%>%
      summarize(mean(time))
    
  })
  
  
  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    data_subset()
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**01/11 until 05/11 works**

[image]

**02/11 until 05/11 does not work.**

[image]

**01/11 until 02/11 it shows the averages, however, it would not have to show**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(dplyr)

Test <- structure(list(date1 = as.Date(c("2021-11-01","2021-11-01","2021-11-01","2021-11-01")),
                       date2 = as.Date(c("2021-10-22","2021-10-22","2021-10-29","2021-10-29")),
                       Week = c("Friday", "Friday", "Friday", "Friday"),
                       Category = c("FDE", "ABC", "FDE", "ABC"),
                       time = c(4, 6, 6, 3)), class = "data.frame",row.names = c(NA, -4L))

ui <- fluidPage(

  shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
                    br(),
                    tabPanel("",
                             sidebarLayout(
                               sidebarPanel(
                                 uiOutput('daterange')
                               ),
                               mainPanel(
                                 dataTableOutput('table')

                               )
                             ))
  ))

server <- function(input, output,session) {

  data <- reactive(Test)

  output$daterange <- renderUI({
    dateRangeInput("daterange1", "Period you want to see:",
                   min   = min(data()$date1))
  })

  observe({updateDateRangeInput(session,"daterange1",start = NA, end = NA)})
  
  wk_port2eng <- data.frame(
    WeekE = c("Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"),
    WeekP = c("segunda-feira", "terca-feira", "quarta-feira", "quinta-feira",  "sexta-feira", "sabado", "domingo")
  )
  
  data_subset <- reactive({
    req(input$daterange1)
    req(input$daterange1[1] <= input$daterange1[2])
    days <- seq(input$daterange1[1], input$daterange1[2], by = 'day')

    Test1 <- dplyr::filter(data(), date1 %in% days)
    weeks_inp <- unique(weekdays(days))  
    wk <- wk_port2eng[wk_port2eng$WeekP %in% weeks_inp,]  ###  if weekday is in Portuguese in your notebook
    #wk <- wk_port2eng[wk_port2eng$WeekE %in% weeks_inp,]  ###  if weekday is in English in your notebook
    weeks_ine <- wk$WeekE
    print(weeks_ine)
    
    meanTest1 <- data() %>%
      group_by(Week,Category) %>%
      dplyr::summarize(mean(time))
    meanTest <- meanTest1[meanTest1$Week %in% as.character(weeks_ine),]
    meanTest
  })

  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    data_subset()
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks. `date1` serves as a limit date on my calendr, so that when you run the APP, it's only showing days after 01/11. `date2` is just information refering to the day the informtion was regitred, and they are alwys dates befor `date1`. In relation to the calendr, see that there are only dates after 01/11(`date1`), so I would like the code to identfy the day of the week chosen in the calendr, so if I chose to check until 05/11 (Friday) , would show the table with the avrages, if it was 04/11 (Thursday), it wouldn't. I don't know if it was clearer?

Comment: I don't understand your reply, but the idea is to generate the table with the averages only for dates after `date1`. If I choose to see from 02/11 to 04/11, for example, the table would not be shown, because in that interval there is no Friday. However, if you choose from 02/11 to 05/11, it would show the table, as 05/11 is a Friday.

Comment: Antonio, please try the updated code,

Comment: I tested @YBS, did it work for you? I did a test for 02/11 to 05/11, for example, but it doesn't show any results.

Comment: It works for me.  I will put an image.

Comment: Wow, how strange! I got exactly your code and ran it in RStudio. Could you please test your inserted code again?

Comment: Yes, this code works for me, and I have posted it again.  The output is from my code.

Comment: Perhaps you should restart your laptop or RStudio.

Comment: I restarted RStudio and it still didn't work, now I'm going to restart the notebook, I'm going to test, then I'll let you know. Could it be a mistake because I live in Brazil and Friday here in my country is Sexta-feira? This cannot generate any error or do you think not?

Comment: I restarted the notebook and Rstudio, but it didn't work for me, I'm trying to figure out what it can be. I used the `print (weeks)` and put it to see from 01/11 to 05/11 and the following appears in the console: `[1] "segunda-feira" "terca-feira" "quarta-feira" "quinta-feira "  "sexta-feira" summarise() has grouped output by 'Week'. You can override using the groups argument.` These are the days of the week written in Portuguese.

Comment: Yes! monday is segunda-feira, tuesday is terça-feira, wednesday is quarta-feira, thursday is quinta-feira, friday is sexta-feira, saturday is sabado and sunday is domingo.  Regarding the previous answer, I showed 5 days because I selected in the daterange an interval of 5 days, 01/11 to 05/11. I'm now trying to update some packages to see if this might be a problem.

Comment: Thanks @YBS, I made this your new edition for Portuguese and it worked =). I still don't understand why you needed to make this change to be honest. Can you explain to me? Another thing I noticed, I inserted in my `Test` database, a record that has Saturday, that is, I have an average now to Saturday too, but when I go to check, for example, from 01/11 to 06/11, it shows just friday averages, wouldn't that show saturday too? If you want, I can ask you a new question about it so I don't prolong it here any longer.

Comment: Please try the updated code.  I had kept Saturday and Sunday in English as I did not know how to write in Portuguese.  It is fixed now.  The days are in Portuguese in your computer.  So I am getting the English names of the selected days from the dataframe `wk_port2eng`.

Comment: Thank you very much friend, I don't even know how to thank you! Thanks for all the help, this one I couldn't solve without your help. Thank you very much!

Comment: Sorry @YBS to interrupt you again, but a little problem came up for me: in relation to this issue of converting days of the week. You considered that the week column in my database is like "Monday," "Tuesday", "Wednesday", ie it starts with a capital letter, but in my database, I have some information written in a small letter, ie "monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", so therefore the information was not showed when run the APP. How can I adjust this so that the code identifies that Monday or monday is the same thing? Do you know? Thanks again!

Comment: You can use tolower(WeekE) in the above.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work! Could you enter in your code above? that way I can check if I'm not doing anything wrong.

Comment: As this is a separate issue, please ask a separate question, which can replicate your issue.

Comment: any idea to this question @YBS? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69860250/strange-error-the-table-is-correctly-generated-by-rstudio-but-not-by-the-site It's same the code this issue that you solved, but when I use it on the website it doesn't work right, only on RStudio, what do you think it could be?