# Strange error: the table is correctly generated by Rstudio, but not by the site I created

Tags: r, shiny

I would like some help from you: The code in shiny below works great. From the dates selected by the `daterange` (in this case I inserted from 01/11 to 07/11), I can get the averages for Friday and Sunday, as shown in Figure 1. In this case, I'm using the app by RStudio. Later, I deployed this app (https://testeeeeeeee.shinyapps.io/antonio/), but when I go to check on the same dates, it doesn't appear Friday, only Sunday (see Figure 2). Do you know what is going on?

Please, if you are unable to reproduce the error, could you tell me what you think it may be, thank you friends!

**Code below:**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(dplyr)
library(tools)
library(DT)

Test <- structure(list(date1 = as.Date(c("2021-11-01","2021-11-01","2021-11-01","2021-11-01")),
                       date2 = as.Date(c("2021-10-22","2021-10-22","2021-10-28","2021-10-30")),
                       Week = c("Friday", "Friday", "Sunday", "Sunday"),
                       Category = c("FDE", "FDE", "FDE", "FDE"),
                       time = c(4, 6, 6, 3)), class = "data.frame",row.names = c(NA, -4L))

ui <- fluidPage(
    
    shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
                      br(),
                      tabPanel("",
                               sidebarLayout(
                                   sidebarPanel(
                                       uiOutput('daterange')
                                   ),
                                   mainPanel(
                                       dataTableOutput('table')
                                       
                                   )
                               ))
    ))

server <- function(input, output,session) {
    
    data <- reactive(Test)
    
    output$daterange <- renderUI({
        dateRangeInput("daterange1", "Period you want to see:",
                       min   = min(data()$date1))
    })
    
    observe({updateDateRangeInput(session,"daterange1",start = NA, end = NA)})
    
    wk_port2eng <- data.frame(
        WeekE = c("Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"),
        WeekP = c("segunda-feira", "terca-feira", "quarta-feira", "quinta-feira",  "sexta-feira", "sabado", "domingo")
    )
    
    data_subset <- reactive({
        req(input$daterange1)
        req(input$daterange1[1] <= input$daterange1[2])
        days <- seq(input$daterange1[1], input$daterange1[2], by = 'day')
        Test1 <- dplyr::filter(data(), date1 %in% days)
        weeks_inp <- unique(weekdays(days))  
        wk <- wk_port2eng[wk_port2eng$WeekP %in% weeks_inp,]  ###  if weekday is in Portuguese in your notebook
        #wk <- wk_port2eng[wk_port2eng$WeekE %in% weeks_inp,]  ###  if weekday is in English in your notebook

        weeks_ine <- wk$WeekE
        meanTest1 <- data() %>%
            group_by(Week = tools::toTitleCase(Week), Category) %>% 
            summarise(mean = mean(time, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop')
        meanTest <- meanTest1[meanTest1$Week %in% as.character(weeks_ine),]
        meanTest
    })
    
    output$table <- renderDataTable({
        data_subset()
    })
    
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**Figure 1**

[image]

**Figure 2**

[image]

**New figures**

*For RStudio*
[image]

*For shiny server*
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `wk_port2eng` dataframe `WeekE` corresponds to what is in your dataframe `Test`, and `WeekP` corresponds to what your system (notebook) spits out.  Now, WeekS corresponds to what is printed when you run it on the Shiny server.  Therefore, you need to update `WeekS` to match the output from the shiny server. At least `terca` and `sabado` needs to be updated as they have special character, which I don't have on my key board.  Try this

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(dplyr)

Test <- structure(list(date1 = as.Date(c("2021-11-01","2021-11-01","2021-11-01","2021-11-01")),
                       date2 = as.Date(c("2021-10-22","2021-10-22","2021-10-29","2021-10-29")),
                       Week = c("Friday", "Friday", "Friday", "Friday"),
                       Category = c("FDE", "ABC", "FDE", "ABC"),
                       time = c(4, 6, 6, 3)), class = "data.frame",row.names = c(NA, -4L))

ui <- fluidPage(

  shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
                    br(),
                    tabPanel("",
                             sidebarLayout(
                               sidebarPanel(
                                 uiOutput('daterange')
                               ),
                               mainPanel( verbatimTextOutput("t1"),
                                 dataTableOutput('table')

                               )
                             ))
  ))

server <- function(input, output,session) {

  data <- reactive(Test)

  output$daterange <- renderUI({
    dateRangeInput("daterange1", "Period you want to see:",
                   min   = min(data()$date1))
  })

  observe({updateDateRangeInput(session,"daterange1",start = NA, end = NA)})

  wk_port2eng <- data.frame(
    WeekE = c("Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"),
    WeekP = c("segunda-feira", "terca-feira", "quarta-feira", "quinta-feira",  "sexta-feira", "sabado", "domingo"),
    WeekS = c("segunda", "terca", "quarta", "quinta",  "sexta", "sabado", "domingo")
  )

  output$t1 <- renderPrint({
    req(input$daterange1)
    req(input$daterange1[1] <= input$daterange1[2])
    days <- seq(input$daterange1[1], input$daterange1[2], by = 'day')
    print(weekdays(days))
  })

  data_subset <- reactive({
    req(input$daterange1)
    req(input$daterange1[1] <= input$daterange1[2])
    days <- seq(input$daterange1[1], input$daterange1[2], by = 'day')

    Test1 <- dplyr::filter(data(), date1 %in% days)
    weeks_inp <- unique(weekdays(days))
    wk <- wk_port2eng[((wk_port2eng$WeekP %in% weeks_inp) | (wk_port2eng$WeekS %in% weeks_inp)),]  ###  if weekday is in Portuguese in your notebook
    #wk <- wk_port2eng[(wk_port2eng$WeekE %in% weeks_inp),]  ###  if weekday is in English in your notebook
    weeks_ine <- wk$WeekE
    print(weeks_ine)

    meanTest1 <- data() %>%
      group_by(Week,Category) %>%
      dplyr::summarize(mean(time))
    meanTest <- meanTest1[meanTest1$Week %in% as.character(weeks_ine),]
    meanTest
  })

  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    data_subset()
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks YBS, I did exactly what you asked. From RStudio it says "segunda-feira", "terca-feira"... whereas from the shiny server it says "segunda", "terca". What do I need to do then, because then if I change it it won't work in RStudio only on the shiny server. I inserted two new images into the question for you to see.

Comment: Updated code should work in both RStudio and the server, once you update `WeekS` terms to match those from the server.